# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have just updated my React app to 16.6.0 and react-scripts to 2.0.3 to start using lazy and I got this error when following an example on official docs:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Disregarding of it everything seems to be working, except this error in the console.

Here is some of my code:

```
// imports here
... 
const Decks = lazy(() => import('./pages/Decks'));
...
class App extends Component {
      ...

    render() {
        return (
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <div>
                    <MenuAppBar />

                    <div style={{paddingTop: '4rem'}}>
                        <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoading />}>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                                <Route path="/decks" component={Decks} />
                                ...
                            </Switch>
                        </Suspense>
                    </div>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        );
    }
```

...
}

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a lazy loaded component, you would need to supply it to the Route component like

```
// imports here
... 
const Decks = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Decks'));
...
class App extends Component {
      ...

    render() {
        return (
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <div>
                    <MenuAppBar />

                    <div style={{paddingTop: '4rem'}}>
                        <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoading />}>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                                <Route path="/decks" render={(props) => <Decks {...props} />} />
                                ...
                            </Switch>
                        </Suspense>
                    </div>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        );
    }
... 
}
```

Probably its an incorrect PropType check in react-router and may have been fixed in the latest versions to make it compatible with react v16.6

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But also I have noticed that it is working anyway and I do not see that error in the production build.

Comment: In production build PropType warnings are anyway not shown, Its just that the PropType check in react router wouldn't be updated for 16.6 version of react

Comment: Your advise did help. Thank you!

Comment: where does 'lazy' come from??

Comment: @Nibb, Lazy can be imported from React. Updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

Update "react-router-dom" to "^4.4.0-beta.6" cat fix it.

It is a bug: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420#issuecomment-435171740

Comment: [As `react-router-dom@4.4.0` was removed from npm and major versions 5.x.x are backwards compatible to 4.x.x](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5/), give `react-router-dom@5.1.0` are try.